# Could not get the ReportViewer dll's in GAC

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am trying to load ReportViewer dll's into the GAC. I downloaded the ReportViewer.exe from Microsoft's download website, Unblocked it and ran it as administrator. The installation of package was successful according to the installation setup program. However, these dll's are not available in the GAC as well as anywhere in my computer's hard drive.

Here is the Link to the ReportViewer information site ( [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) )
Here is the link to the ReportViewer.exe download site( [enter link description here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442) ).

How do I get these dll's installed on my pc running on windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My dll's by default were installed to:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer
On 64bit Windows 7

You can try looking there. If they are there you can add them to the GAC manually.
Try looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx)